# Copy Colors but not conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me to understand how to Copy Colors from a specific cell but not conditional formatting.

For example

My Range A1 and A2 are merged cell with red color and with some value on it and I have to copy only that red color to Range B1 and B2 which have some different values. Is there any provision to satisfy it?

I tried

```
Range("A1:A2").Copy

Range("B1:B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

but this will copy paste and merge the cell B1 and B2

Comment: Can't you use `.FormatConditions.Delete` on the target range once you copy? Not optimal, but it might be the easier way of implementing it to your code

Comment: i dont get it sorry....

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to copy paste vales while keeping the formatting but removing the Conditional Formatting, right? If this is the case, after you paste your values onto `Range("B1:B2")`, do `Range("B1:B2").FormatConditions.Delete` , this should remove the conditional formatting of the range. Or do you wish to copy the cells and preserve the formatting applied by Conditional Formatting without it being conditional?

Comment: I don't want to change/update the values I have on B1 and B2, I just want to get the color I have under A1 & and A2 to B1 & B2 without merging the cells.

Comment: If you want the color of a cell after conditional formatting has been applied then you need `Cells(1,1).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

Answer (score 2):

I would create a function to detect the backcolor (.Interor) if desired cells, and store these values as your “Copied colors”.

Example of a function to get the RGB-value of a desired cell:

```
Function getRGB(rcell) As String
    Dim colorVal As String

    colorVal = Right("000000" & Hex(rcell.Interior.Color), 6)
    getRGB = Right(colorVal, 2) & Mid(colorVal, 3, 2) & Left(colorVal, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: @user9184557, if this answer did in fact turn out to be the answer to your question, please mark it so. Other users may also have the same question, and it's good practice to let them know it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy A1:A2 and paste directly in a new ms-word doc. Then again copy this from ms-word and paste it anywhere in excel (say C1:C2). Now copy format from C1:C2 and paste at required range as mentioned B1:B2. Delete C1:C2 now. This is how I manege in such scenario !!

Answer (score 0):

The issue of copying to a word document, remove the figure but retain the colours and paste back to excel. Works perfectly okay. This world most times need simple solutions.